# Convert data returned by mongoose to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am printing my entire collections with this piece in routes/index.js

```
exports.create = function(req,res){
new checklist_model({
        name : req.body.name,
                comment : req.body.comment
               }).save(function(err,checklist_model){
        res.redirect('/');
        });
};

    exports.checklist = function ( req, res ){ 
      checklist_model.find({},function ( err,checklist_data,count ){
        res.render( 'checklist', {
          title : 'checklist',
          checklist_data : JSON.stringify(checklist_data)
        });console.log(checklist_data);
      });
    };
```

I get the collection data in the format below:

```
{ name: 'Stats',
    comment: 'Functionality test',
    _id: 53c5f7cdb79a40232193c45e,
    __v: 0 }
```

How do I get this to print in JSON format?

```
{ "name": "Stats",
    "comment": "Functionality test",
    "_id": "53c5f7cdb79a40232193c45e",
    "__v": "0" }
```

Thanks

EDIT: 
Soulcheck made a great suggestion about converting data to json and it "works", but when i try to 
use "checklist_data" from code( mentioned above under routes/index.js) in my checklist.jade nothing is happens. (I am trying to use script tags first, just to understand how it actually works)

```
<script language="javascript" class="lookhere">
  var myJason = JSON.parse(checklist_data);
  var result = myJason.row;
  console.log(result);
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
      {
         var object = result[i];
         for (property in object)
         {
               var value = object[property];
               alert(property + "=" + value);
         }
      }
</script>
```

checklist.jade:

```
| doctype html
| html.
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    title Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Vertical Form Layout
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    style(type='text/css')
      .bs-example{
      margin: 20px;
      }
  body
    form.bs-example(action='/create', method='post')
      .form-group
        label(for='name')
        input#name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Enter Name', name='name')
        label(for='name')
        textarea.form-control(rows='3', name='comment') Enter Comments
      button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
    script.lookhere(language='javascript')
      var myJason = JSON.parse(checklist_data);
      var result = myJason.row;
      console.log(result);
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
      {
      var object = result[i];
      for (property in object)
      {
      var value = object[property];
      alert(property + "=" + value);
      }
      }
```

EDIT_2:

My JSON populates like this below

```
 var myJason = JSON.parse([{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;comment&quot;:&quot;testing&quot;,&quot;_id&quot;:&quot;53ceccae51f13e5f2d9003db&quot;,&quot;__v&quot;:0}]);
```

and i get the error just after this line.

```
:3004/:25Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be your problem is the fact that you're mixing the ways the object is represented.

When you do `console.log(data)` you probably get:

```
{ 
     name: 'Stats',
     comment: 'Functionality test',
     _id: 53c5f7cdb79a40232193c45e,
     __v: 0 
}
```

This is correct - `console.log` doesn't serialize objects to JSON, it serializes them as javascript object literals instead (and other related strings for arrays, functions, etc).

Now the `JSON.stringify(checklist_data)` call will almost certainly give you the desired result, that is:

```
{ "name": "Stats",
"comment": "Functionality test",
"_id": "53c5f7cdb79a40232193c45e",
"__v": "0" }
```

Now if you want to print the actual JSON, use:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(checklist_data));
```

You were almost there in your code, but you called `console.log` with not yet serialized object.

*edit*
Ok looking at your code you're better off not deserializing from JSON at all.

So in your node code do:

```
   res.render( 'checklist', {
      title : 'checklist',
      checklist_data : Json.stringify(checklist_data)
   })
```

and then in your jade template:

```
  script.lookhere(language='javascript')
  var myJason = !{checklist_data};
  var result = myJason.row;
  console.log(result);
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
  {
  ....
```

Remember, JSON is a valid javascript object literal.

Comment: Thanks for the help soulcheck. This solution works perfectly but  I am not sure why this is not picking up the data. `    <script language="javascript" class="lookhere">
      var myJason = JSON.parse(checklist_data);
      var result = myJason.row;
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
          {
             var object = result[i];
             for (property in object)
             {
                   var value = object[property];
                   alert(property + "=" + value);
             }
          }
    </script>`

Comment: You need to show us the 'checklist' template you tried to render.

Comment: No, I meant the template on the server-side you called 'checklist'. You're doing: `res.render( 'checklist', {
      title : 'checklist',
      checklist_data : JSON.stringify(checklist_data)
    })` in your code. `res.render` renders a server-side template and sends it to the client. You need to show us the jade template.

Comment: Apologies, i miss understood .I have added checklist.jade template. I changed the javascript tags to jade if that helps.

Comment: You need to change `var myJason = JSON.parse(checklist_data);` to `var myJason = JSON.parse(#{checklist_data});`

Comment: Sorry about delay in replying. I tested what you have suggested and it does not seem to like the "&" signs.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, forgot quotes and to turn of filtering : var myJason = JSON.parse('!{checklist_data}'). But really you're better off avoiding the whole stringify/parse here and just passing the object directly, since you can always stumble at some character javascript doesn't like (like quotes).

Comment: First, sorry for delay, was busy with something. I tested this and it works. Thank you for all your help Soulcheck.I Appreciate it.